# Efficiently reusing arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

For the program below, I want to keep the double array c to be reused in another function. I don't want to use an ArrayList. I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas as to how to approach this problem in an efficient manner.

Edit: I forgot to mention the double array c is going to change sizes. Is there a way to delete the array and then recreate the array in a different size?

```
public double[][] forwardAlgo(){
    int time = eSequence.size();
    double alpha[][] = new double[2][time];
    double c[] = new double[time];

    // Intialize alpha for time 0
    c[0] = 0; // c0 is for scaling purposes to avoid underflow
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
        alpha[i][0] = pi[i] * emissionMatrix[i][eSequence.get(0)];
        c[0] = c[0] + alpha[i][0];
    }

    // Scale alpha_0
    c[0] = 1 / c[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        alpha[i][0] = c[0]*alpha[i][0];
        System.out.format("%f, ", alpha[i][0]);
    }

    // Use recursive method to calculate alpha
    double tempAlpha = 0;
    for(int t = 1; t < time; t++){
        c[t] = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                tempAlpha = tempAlpha + alpha[j][t-1] * stateTransitionMatrix[j][i];
            }
            alpha[i][t] = tempAlpha * emissionMatrix[i][eSequence.get(t)];
            c[t] = c[t] + alpha[i][t];
            tempAlpha = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int t = 1; t < time; t++){
        c[t] = 1 / c[t];
        for(int i = 0; i < time; i++){
            alpha[i][t] = alpha[i][t] * c[t];
        }
    }

    return alpha;
}
```

Comment: make your array an instance variable. that way other methods can access it.

Comment: then just make your array the field of class, what's the problem?

Comment: yeah i wanted to do that but the array size is going to change. is there a way to delete the array and recreate it in a new size?

Comment: make it big, but don't use the whole thing. keep a separate `size` variable instead of using arr.length. this way you dont need to reallocate or copy elements over when changing the size.

Comment: When you store it as a field / instance variable, you can create it with a new size at any point with `c = new double[newSize];`.

Comment: If the new size will be different, don't bother trying to reuse the old array. (OK, yes, you could do so if the new size is smaller... but that microoptimization is really Not Worth It unless this is a huge array or you're creating a metric ton of them.)

Comment: Suppose you have `double[] c = new double[5]` and then you want it to be of size 500. Just reassign the variable like that: `c = new double[500]` and use it from now on. The previous array of size 5 will be garbage-collected and you don't have to worry about it no more.

Comment: oooh i see thank you Marco13 and cdshines !
@keshlam I will keep that in mind